# TF.js load object detection model in model.json format in browser

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, object-detection-api

I've trained a .pb object detection model in python using Colab and converted it to the model.json format using the [TensorFlow converter](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/conversion). I need to load this model inside the browser (no Node.js!) and run inference there.
This is the structure of my model folder the [TensorFlow converter](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/conversion) produced:

```
model
| - model.json
| - labels.json
| - group1-shard1of2.bin
| - group1-shard2of2.bin
```

The [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load) suggest the following to load such a model:

```
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel('model/model.json');
```

or

```
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('model/model.json');
```

I am using the `tf.loadGraphModel` function. Loading the model works flawlessly, but when I try to run inference with it using this code:

```
// detect objects in the image.
const img = document.getElementById('img'); 
model.predict(img).then(predictions => {
    console.log('Predictions: ');
    console.log(predictions);
});
```

it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: The dict provided in model.execute(dict) has keys [...] that are not part of graph
at e.t.checkInputs (graph_executor.js:607)
at e.t.execute (graph_executor.js:193)
at e.t.execute (graph_model.js:338)
at e.t.predict (graph_model.js:291)
at predictImages (detector.php:39)
```

Am I using the wrong loading function, did the model loading process fail (even though it didn't throw any errors?) or is the inference function wrong?
Thanks in advance for your support!

**EDIT:** After using @edkeveked's suggestion to convert the image to a tensor first using this code:

```
const tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(img);
```

and running inference using this:

```
model.predict(tensor.expandDims(0));
```

I got this error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: This execution contains the node 'Preprocessor/map/while/Exit_2', which has the dynamic op 'Exit'. Please use model.executeAsync() instead. Alternatively, to avoid the dynamic ops, specify the inputs [Preprocessor/map/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3]
    at e.t.compile (graph_executor.js:162)
    at e.t.execute (graph_executor.js:212)
    at e.t.execute (graph_model.js:338)
    at e.t.predict (graph_model.js:291)
    at predictImages (detector.php:38)
```

After replacing `model.predict()` with `model.executeAsync()`, it returned a result that was not what I expected to get from an object detection model:

```
detector.php:40 (2) [e, e]0: e {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(3), dtype: "float32", size: 3834, …}1: e {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(4), dtype: "float32", size: 7668, …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```

This is my complete code so far (images added in HTML using PHP):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.8.3/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load the coco-ssd model. -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd@1.1.0"></script>

    <script>
    async function predictImages() { // async
        console.log("loading model");
        // Load the model.
        const model = await tf.loadGraphModel('model/model.json');
        console.log("model loaded.");
        
        // predict for all images
        for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            const img = document.getElementById('img' + i); // check if image exists if (img
            if (img != null) {
                console.log("doc exists: " + 'img' + i);
                const tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(img);
                model.executeAsync(tensor.expandDims(0)).then(predictions => {
                    console.log('Predictions: ');
                    console.log(predictions);
                });
             
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    predictImages();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.predict` expects a tensor but it is given an HTMLImageElement. First a tensor needs to be constructed from the HTMLImageElement.

```
const tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(img)
```

And then the tensor can be used as the parameter to `model.predict`

```
model.predict(tensor) // returns a 3d
```

Last but not the least is to make sure that the tensor shape is the one expected by the model (3d or 4d). If the model expects a 4d, then it should rather be

```
model.predict(tensor.expandDims(0))
```

Comment: Loading the image as you suggested works flawlessly, but when I run prediction using the code I added in my question, it returns this: `detector.php:40 (2) [e, e]0: e {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(3), dtype: "float32", size: 3834, …}1: e {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(4), dtype: "float32", size: 7668, …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)` What is the problem with my code?

Comment: There is not issue with the code. `predictions` is an array of tensors. And if you want to get its value, you will need to do `predictions[index].dataSync()` with index being either 0 or 1

Comment: Converting the tensor array to get its value, it returns a Float32Array(7668), but I need bounding boxes and their labels in the JSON-format. How can I achieve that?

Comment: It depends on what is the output of your model. However, If you want the return data to keep the same shape as the tensor, you can use `arraySync` instead of `dataSync`

Comment: But how can I get the bounding box coordinates from the tensors? I want to crop my images to the bounding boxes.

Comment: I think it is another question. You can closed this one and open a new question showing the output you currently have

Comment: Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65652335/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-bounding-box-coordinates-and-labels-in-javascrip

Comment: You can upvote this answer and mark it as accepted since it solves your initial issue about predicting from the image :)

Comment: Do you know an answer to my new question? If so, please answer it so I can work on my project.